# How to get Mac OS X printer preset to save paper size and not default to system default paper size?

Tags: macos, printing

I have a receipt printer and regular printer on my Mac and have the system default paper size set to Letter and default printer set to "Last Used"

In Safari I've setup a preset for my receipt printer but when I select it, the paper size still defaults to letter instead of the receipt paper.

I change the paper size to receipt size, select "Save current settings as preset" and all settings are saved in preset except the paper size.

How can I get the preset to save the paper size?

Comment: So you have two (2) printers in your System Preference ..Printer! For each you have set the default printing properties! So what is your question.

Answer (score 1):

The Printing from Safari setup sequence for multiple printers.

Click on Print and in the pop up choose your printer and the settings you saved for it.

[image]

[image: It will show it correctly in Presets]

It will show it correctly in Presets!

When saving you will be asked for which printer the settings apply.

[image]

Comment: Does not work atleast in 10.6.8. The plist shows its saved, but the print dialog does not reflect the correct saved paper size.

Answer (score 0):

The setting can only be overridden in the GUI by using an application that supports the *Page Setup* menu option. Apple’s apps such as Mail and Safari no longer have this menu item.

From an app that has Page Setup, make sure your preferred paper size is set correctly and in the Settings menu choose *Save As Default*.

If you want to try using the terminal, this website has a guide to key values:
[Setting a Default Paper Size](http://themacadmin.com/setting-a-default-paper-size/)